# Android Rect.intersects not working?

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, intersection, rectangles

I want to check if two rectangles are intersecting each other! I have a GLObject class, which represent Items, which are rendered on the screen. And my Game class, which make other game stuff. The rendering with OpenGLEs 2.0 works! The 2 Items are displayed correctly, but if i move the one Item into the other nothing happens.. The rectangles and vertices are correct (Proof: right positions of textures on screen/Log output)

In Game class:

```
@Override
public void Process(long elapsed)
{
    // TODO: Implement this method
    super.Process(elapsed);

    Rect r1 = mtest1.getRect(); // get Rectangle
    Rect r2 = mtest2.getRect();

    if (Rect.intersects(r1, r2)) // always false
        System.exit(0);

    //Log.e("logpos", "left" + r1.left + " top" + r1.top + " right" + r1.right + " bottom" + r1.bottom);
    //this logs the correct position:
    //left830 top200 right920 bottom100 for r1
    //left810 top200 right900 bottom100 for r2

    r1 = r2; // make them equal for testing

    if (Rect.intersects(r1, r2)) // always flase
        System.exit(0);
}
```

In my GLObject class:

```
private float mRect[] =
{
    //counterclockwise
    10.0f, 200f,  0.0f, // top left
    10.0f, 100f,  0.0f, // bottom left
    100f,  100f,  0.0f, // bottom right
    100f,  200f,  0.0f  // top right
};

//...

public Rect getRect()
{
    return new Rect((int)mRect[0], 
                    (int)mRect[1], 
                    (int)mRect[6],
                    (int)mRect[4]);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i have the solution:
The coordinate system of my OpenGL Scene and the Android Rect Class are different:

```
^
I
I
I        OpenGL
I
I
I===========================>


I===========================>
I
I
I     Android Rect Class
I 
I
v
```

(landscape)

I changed the Ortho and now it is working.